# Take count of repeating words in file

Tags: c#, .net

I have code to take count of repeating words in file

Here it is

```
static void Main()
    {
        StreamReader f = new StreamReader(@"d:\C#\text.txt");
        string s = f.ReadToEnd();
        char[] separators = { };//here is symbols
        List<string> words = new List<string>(s.Split(separators));
        Dictionary<string, int> map = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (string w in words) 
            if (map.ContainsKey(w)) map[w]++; else map[w] = 1;
        foreach (string w in map.Keys)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{l}", w.map[w]);
    }
```

But in this row `Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{l}", w.map[w]);` I have this error.

> Error CS1061  'string' does not contain a definition for 'map' and no extension method 'map' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

How I can fix this error?

Comment: What do you think `w.map[w]` is doing?

Comment: Displaying values@litelite

Comment: Nope, it's trying to call a method called `map` on `w` because you put a `.` in between them. You have a typo. Replace the `.` between `w` and `map` by a `,`.

Comment: As already pointed out by @litelite, you have a `.` instead of `,` in `Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{l}", w.map[w])`. `{0}{1}` implies you will be passing 2 parameters(`w` and `map[w]`) to the StringBuilder, though instead you are passing `w.map[w]`, which is an invalid _object_, while `w` and `map[w]` are the 2 valid _objects_ you are trying to pass. The term _object_ is used loosely here...

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code - in you case it should be something like `"bob".map[1]` instead of all those extra lines.

Answer (score 1):

If I undertood what you wanted, this will help:

```
List<string> words = new List<string>() { "c#", "html", "web service", "c#", "c#" };

Dictionary<string, int> map = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (string w in words)
{
    if (map.ContainsKey(w))
    {
        map[w] = map[w]+1;
    }
    else
    {
        map[w] = 1;
    }
}

//to iterate through Dictionary<string, int> use this instead
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in map)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Key}\t{entry.Value}");
}
```